# How to setup CouchDB with JWT auth?

Tags: database, authentication, jwt, couchdb

I'm trying to setup just for CouchDB, so I can use my current API tokens to authenticate in CouchDB.
But the docs don't seem to provide enough information to set this up.

I don't understand what the payload of the gut needs to contain identifying the user. How do I configure the jwt secret?

Is there any simple example out there or something like or tutorial to do this correctly?

Comment: Have you already looked at the official documentation: [JWT Authentication](https://docs.couchdb.org/en/3.2.0/api/server/authn.html#jwt-authentication)? Which payload do yu mean? If you mean the payload of your request it must of course contain jwt token in `Authorization: Bearer <your jwt token>` header. CouchDB itself must be configured to verify the token with the appropriate key of the party that issued the token (your authorization server).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this thread may be helpful:
https://github.com/apache/couchdb/discussions/2947
edit:
ok i found a configuration that worked for me - this solution won't be suitable for anything more than a testing couchdb instance.

1. configure local.ini (docker image)
   1.1 -> ssh to your docker docker exec -it  bash
   1.2 -> install vim for convenience and disable visual mode:

```
$ apt-get update           
$ apt-get install vim 
$ echo "set mouse-=a" >> ~/.vimrc
```

1.3 -> update local.ini

```
$ vi /opt/couchdb/etc/local.ini
```

in [chttpd] section add line

```
authentication_handlers = {chttpd_auth, jwt_authentication_handler}, {chttpd_auth, cookie_authentication_handler}, {chttpd_auth, default_authentication_handler}
```

at the very end of the file add jwt_keys config

```
[jwt_keys]
hmac:_default = aGVsbG8=
hmac:foo = aGVsbG8y
```

restart your container

2. configure postman :

bearer token for _default hmac is

```
eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJzdWIiOiJ1c2VyXzEiLCJleHAiOjE1OTI2MTEyMDB9.Y9jNgSeSBl54V2MHg1hXhivyZsdXTeiAVJR2DSlF6LQ
```

put it into postman and issue following get request:

```
http://localhost:5984/_session
```

you should see something like :

```
{"ok":true,"userCtx":{"name":"user_1","roles":[]},"info":{"authentication_handlers":["jwt","cookie","default"],"authenticated":"jwt"}}
```

now go in your browser to couchdb ui and login as admin
http://127.0.0.1:5984/_utils/#login
then click the "lock" icon next to the database you wish the user_1 to have privileges and update the permissions accordingly.

3. check
   check if your user_1 authenticating via jwt has permissions on the database by issuing appropriate request, for example

```
http://localhost:5984/campaigns
```

Answer (score 4):

After install CouchDB, open Fauxton > Configuration, + Add Option with:

```
Section = chttpd
Name = authentication_handlers
Value = {chttpd_auth, cookie_authentication_handler}, {chttpd_auth, jwt_authentication_handler}, {chttpd_auth, default_authentication_handler}
```

Generate a base64 encoded secret with:

```bash
echo -n 'supersecret' | openssl base64
```

This command will output: `c3VwZXJzZWNyZXQ=`

Obvious you will replace 'supersecret' with your own and stronger secret

Edit /opt/couchdb/etc/local.d/10-admins.ini and add

```ini
[jwt_keys]
hmac:_default = c3VwZXJzZWNyZXQ=
```

Restart CouchDB

```bash
service couchdb restart
```

Now we need to generate a JSON Web Token to test.

Go to https://jwt.io/, select HS256 algorithm. At VERIFY SIGNATURE type `c3VwZXJzZWNyZXQ=` on the editable field and check "secret base64 encoded"

Important: At `PAYLOAD` set `sub` key to the username of token. eg. `{"sub": "João"}`

Your encoded JWT will be shown on left. Copy it.

Now test with curl:

```bash
curl -H "Authorization: Bearer PASTE_TOKEN_HERE" http://127.0.0.1:5984/_session
```

In my example, the full curl command becames:

```bash
curl -H "Authorization: Bearer eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJzdWIiOiIxMjM0NTY3ODkwIiwibmFtZSI6IkpvaG4gRG9lIiwiaWF0IjoxNTE2MjM5MDIyfQ.zbgd5BNF1cqQ_prCEqIvBTjSxMS8bDLnJAE_wE-0Cxg" http://127.0.0.1:5984/_session
```

You should revice back something like:

```
{"ok":true,"userCtx":{"name":"1234567890","roles":[]},"info":{"authentication_handlers":["cookie","jwt","default"],"authenticated":"jwt"}}
```

If you get:

```
{"error":"bad_request","reason":"Bad HMAC"}
```

You have made some mistake. Verify all steps and try again.

References:

https://github.com/softapalvelin/couch_jwt_auth
https://docs.couchdb.org/en/stable/api/server/authn.html#jwt-authentication